# Definitions of connectedness on rings

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, connectedness

I've encountered a few possible definitions of a "connected ring" and am having some confusion relating them. The first [one is defined for any commutative ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_ring#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20especially%20in%20the,topology%20is%20a%20connected%20space.):

*A commutative connected ring has a spectrum which is connected in the Zariski topology.*

But there is also the concept of a [topological ring](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Topological_ring), where the ring itself (not the spectrum) is endowed with a topology. In this case, it also seems natural to consider a topological ring to be "connected" if the the ring itself is a connected topological space (irrespective of the spectrum). My concrete questions are thus:

1. For a commutative topological ring, is there a relationship between "connectedness" in the spectrum-sense vs in the ring topology-sense? More broadly, is there any relationship between the topologies on the two spaces? They seem unrelated to me.
2. When I read results on ring theory, I'm often confused whether topological statements refer to the ring itself or the spectrum. Take [for example the following](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/08/holy_crap_do_you_know_what_a_c.html):
   *Every compact Hausdorff ring is totally disconnected.* I'm assuming here that the ring in question is a topological ring, and "compact Hausdorff"-ness is refering to the topological properties of the ring itself. But here, is "total disconnected"-ness referring to the ring topology, or to the spectrum topology that results in the definition of a "connected ring" above?

Am I getting tripped up on overloaded terminology here, or is there some deeper connection that I'm missing? Thanks for the help!

Comment: As the wiki page you linked to mentions, the "ring theoretic connected" is equivalent to the ring being connected in the Zariski topology.  It is not necessarily connected with other topological ring structures. You could topologize any ring using the discrete topology, no?  That would mean it is highly disconnected and yet you could have started with a ring with very few idempotents.

Comment: @rschwieb That was my intuition as well. From what I can tell, it's not the ring itself being connected in the Zariski topology, but the _spectrum_ of the ring being connected. When the ring itself is also a topological space, are these topologies completely independent? Can I choose the topology on the ring to be anything that makes operations continuous, unconstrained by what the Zariski topology on the spectrum looks like? My uncertainty is that in this case "the ring is connected" seems to have two completely different meanings.

Comment: Yes, more precisely I should just say "Spec(R) is connected in the Zariski topology."  The spectrum is the relevant topological space, not the underlying set of the ring with some compatible topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really any significant relationship between these two notions.  The contexts in which you care about them tend to be very different from each other such that it is almost always obvious which one is being talked about in context.  For one thing, if your ring does not have a topology, then only the first meaning can be intended.  On the flip side, if someone is talking about a topological ring (and mentioning the topology), they almost certainly mean connectedness of that topology and if they wanted to talk about the other notion they would instead talk about the spectrum of the ring being connected to avoid confusion.  (This includes the specific example you are asking about: "every compact Hausdorff ring is totally disconnected" is talking about the topology of the ring.)  Generally, connectedness in the ring-theoretic sense is something you would care about when doing algebraic geometry (and your ring is probably closely related to rings of polynomials) and connectedness of a topological ring is something you would care about when studying the general theory of topological rings.